# How to use REST assured?

Tags: rest-assured

I have never used JUnit or other testing frameworks. All i know is how to develop rest service. I recently saw REST assured framework to test REST api. But all the articles that i found looks like below. But i don't know how to pass request xml and how will i get response and when should i call this method.?

Do i need to use some other tool before this REST assured.? I am completely beginner in this kind of testing frameworks. Please show me some light in this world. All i know is how to send request and check values in the response in SOAPUI. I have never tried this.

```
expect().
    statusCode(200).
    body(
      "user.email", equalTo("test@hascode.com"),
      "user.firstName", equalTo("Tim"),
      "user.lastName", equalTo("Testerman"),
      "user.id", equalTo("1")).
    when().
    get("/service/single-user/xml");
```

Answer (score 10):

**expect()** /* what u expect after sending a request to REST Service */

**statusCode(200)** /*you are expecting 200 as statuscode which tells request handled successfully at server */

**body()**
 /* the conditions given in body are compare the value with expected values. "equalTo" hamcrest matcher condition (you need to have hamcrest jar in java classpath).*/

**when().** /* as is name says above all will be done after sending get/post/put/delete request right  so before you put these get,post,put,delete you will  have this method as prefix */

**get("/service/single-user/xml")**
/* the actual REST API request url goes here. can be GET/POST/PUT/DELETE. the confusion for you is its only showing half part which is base path.you can give entire request url in get() method.*/

more on:
http://rest-assured.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.1/apidocs/com/jayway/restassured/RestAssured.html

I hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, when we POST request, we will send some xml format let say, my question is where to send that XML request.


WebResource webResource = client
     .resource("http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/json/metallica/post");
 
  String input = "{\"singer\":\"Metallica\",\"title\":\"Fade To Black\"}";
 
  ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json")
     .post(ClientResponse.class, input);


In the sample snippet above, we are passing input object and getting response back. 

Like that how should i do in REST Assured..? How do we need to provide input obj.

Comment: you can provide under given() method as below given().contentType("application/json").body("{\"singer\":\"Metallica\",\"title\":\"Fade To Black\"}").expect().statuscode(200).when().post("http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/json/metallica/post");

Comment: Can anyone please provide one PUT example for http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/ API, I am trying to add customer entry but it is always failing... my code looks like this -- @Test
 public void addSingleUser() {
   /*expect().
     statusCode(400).*/
  given().
   parameters("ID", "13", "FIRSTNAME", "POL", "LASTNAME", "CRI", "STREET", "1 Main St.", "CITY", "CAD").
  when().
     put("http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/13").
  then().
   body("CUSTOMER.ID", equalTo("13"));
 }

Comment: are u able to do it with any rest client? what error ur getting

Comment: I think I am ok for now, looks like service has some issue.. I tried with other service and it is working fine. thx!